# How to make an object appear and another disappear on click

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I have made an object `"TextBox 3"` saying `"Click me for ________"`. I have successfully made it so when it is is clicked, then it disappears. I then added `"Textbox 4"` and gave the the command so that when `"Textbox 3"` is clicked, it appears. I have successfully done this, but when playing the powerpoint, it requires me to press the `-->` arrow key after `"TextBox 3"` had been clicked to make it appear. How do I make it so that the two actions occur simultaneously?

Feel free to ask for information required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

Select Textbox 4 then on the Animations tab, click Animation Pane.

In the Animation pane click the downward pointing triangle next to Textbox 4 and choose "Start After Previous"

Now the animation will play automatically after the Textbox 3 animation finishes.

You'll also need to make sure that Textbox 3 is *above* Textbox 4 in the Animation pane.